# How to program the PIC32 in Assembly?

Tags: mips, mips32, mplab, pic32

I'm trying to program a PIC32 MM0064GPL028 in Assembly, to do MIPS32 exercises on a real CPU, instead of the simulator that we use in my course (QtSpim), without any success.

The only guide I found on the internet is [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1198462/King-MM-The-Joys-of-a-Harmony-less-Life-Part-1-PIC), but I get an error when I try to build the file.
If somebody could help me or link some useful stuff, that would be amazing

I have also tried to search some Microchip documentation but I can't find a guide for beginners or a book, many of the material is also old

I can't find the "cfg.hpp" library and I don't know why.

This code is from the guide that I have found

```
build/default/production/main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `asm_delay_1_sec'
```

Comment: You had to select the right build tool. And you also had to install XC32 to get the MIPS assembler.

Comment: Did you "create util.S file and then add it to the project"?

Comment: Thank u marjgz, one of my errors was put .s instead of .S in the asm file extesion

Answer (score 2):

some things when you work with MPLABx and MIPS assembler:
- you had to install XC32
- your assembler file should end with `.s`
- you had to add your assembler file to the project

I thing this [document](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51833A.pdf) will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mike, i create the .s file inside the project form MPLABX so it should already be included in it, i tried to include the file in the main script such a library, and it says that there is a problem in the assembly code

Comment: Your are welcome. If you need any further help let me know.

Comment: The idea of this repo is to provide a quickstart for programming a pic32mx Microcontroller without using MPLABX or the XC32 compiler. https://github.com/cpresser/opensource-pic32 I've not tried it yet but it certainly looks interesting.